# C++ different values between variables and debugger

Tags: c++

I'm working in C++ with Visual Studio.

I got a strange case. There is my code (simplified version) :

```
Point GetPoint(/*parameters*/)
{
    float Ax = 149; //Value depending on parameters
    float Ay = 20;
    float Bx = 29;
    float By = 19;
    double pAB = (Ay - By) / (Ax - Bx);
    double Sx = Cx;
    double Sy = pAB * (Cx - Ax) + Ay;
    // Sy = (20 - 19) / (149 - 29) * (29 - 149) + 20.0
    // => Sy = 1 / 120 * -120 + 20
    // => Sy = -1 + 20
    
    return new Point(static_cast<int>(Sx), static_cast<int>(Sy));
}
```

I expected that Sy = 19 but instead my point value is 18. I started the debugger to understand and I found this :

> (Ay - By) / (Ax - Bx) = 0.00833333284
>
> (20.0 - 19.0) / (149.0 - 29.0) = 0.0083333333333333332
>
> pAB = 0.0083333337679505348

And :

> (20.0 - 19.0) / (149.0 - 29.0) * (29.0 - 149.0) + 20.0 = 19
>
> Sy = 18.999999947845936

Final cast set my point to 18 (sy < 19). But the same code in C# give me a 19. Why theses difference ? And how can I get a 19 ?

Comment: "But the same code in C# give me a 19" did you step through the code in c# and write down the same results?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Casting a float to an int will get rid of anything after the decimal value, therefor, `18.999999947845936` will simply become `18`. You can use `std::round' to get proper rounding

Comment: @xEric_xD in C# if you cast to an int it rounds down too... but doesn't touch on the difference between c++ & c#

Comment: @user0042 the problem is close to the other topic, but is doesn't explain me why the same code in C++ and C# don't give same results

Comment: @A.Pissicat It might just be floating point rounding differences, have you checked the values of the floats before casting in both C# and C++?

Comment: Which _same code_? Is there `static_cast` in C#? Use `std::round` and type `double` instead.

Comment: Indeed, do not perform a static cast from a floating point value without at least adding a bias to account for rounding errors. The compiler may choose to reorder your operations, so the error can even vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ and C# are different languages, with different rules and different compilers. Since floating point is inexact by definition, any subtle difference can result in the different values you see.

I don't know the C# rules at all, but in C++, notice that while you have typed `pAB` as `double`, you're actually computing its value in `float` (because `Ax`, `Ay`, `Bx`, `By` are all `float`s) and only after that is the value promoted to a `double`. In other words, you do not gain any precision here by using `double`. Maybe the C# rules are different here, no idea.

Anyway, if you make sure `pAB` is computed in `double`, you get exact values with these particular numbers: [[live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1232b1dd28762ee4), compared to [[the unchanged code]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d409ced501190d7d).

Making sure the `double` value is actually computed in `double` is probably the correct solution here. Nevertheless, since floating point *is* inexact and could "fail" for you with other values, I suggest using [`std::round`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) instead of casting to `int` if you want rounding behaviour.